# Объединить [makefile] и [make]?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [make](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/make) и [makefile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile), сделав вторую
синонимом первой.  Не вижу особой разницы в из использовании.  Можно
было бы, конечно, ввести искусственное разграничение, и сделать первую
метку относящейся к вызову утилиты, а вторую — к
самому файлу, но это как-то странно и не нужно, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Дельное предложение. Вечером просмотрю вопросы)

Comment: А почему не наоборот? А то `make` - как-то слишком абстрактно.

Comment: @Qwertiy  (1)  `make` короче.  (2)  Это название утилиты.  (Мне в общем-то без разницы, на самом деле.  Главное — объединить.)

Comment: @Qwertiy обычно всегда `makefile` используют при обсуждении. И на enSO `makefile` основная. Лучше голосованием решить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не думаю, что перевес голосов как-то сильно изменится относительно текущих. Сделал метку [makefile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile) основной.

Answer (score 6):

Основной сделать [makefile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile) как и на enSO.

Answer (score 3):

Основной сделать [make](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/make), т.к. короче и это название утилиты.